# How to build an application for iPhone using Phonegap so I could send to friends for testing (like the apk for Android)?

Tags: cordova

The questions is self-explanatory. I have build an iOS version of the program and I can run in it in my Xcode emulator.
How can I build an application file so I could send it to my friends for testing?
(Something like building an APK for Android, which I can send to friends)

Step by step guide would be much appreciated. I am using Phonegap 3.3 (and phonegap library not cordova)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have two options:

1. Use build option on phonegap web-site - you upload your www folder and the web-site builds an application file (although I haven't tried it)
2. Use Mac OS and build the application file.

I will explain the second option as the first wasn't too good in my case.

You will need a Mac OS - either a Mac computer or a virtual machine.
For the start you can try without provisioning profile on JailBroken phone (as far as I know JailBraking a phone is not illegal) and follow the instructions on wiki http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode (there was a blog that describes everything perfectly , but I have lost the link)

Eventually you WILL need a developer's account which costs 99 ($, euro's etc.) https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/ , and you will find all the help, step by step perfectly explained on apple's web-site in help center, once you enroll for a program.
Once you set up everything, run following commands in you application folder:

1. `phonegap build local ios`
2. The project will be created in `/platforms/ios/`
3. Open the project in xCode and run on your device (you will find everything on Apple's web-site)